# Add Event at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, events, runtime

my method is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = "btn" + i.ToString();
            btn.Text = "btn" + i.ToString();
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }
    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Button btn = (Button)sender;
        if (btn.Name == "btn1")
        {
            this.Text = "stack";
        }
    }
```

There is a better approach ?

Answer (score 2):

The code you used:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
```

Is the correct code to add the handler. Creating the buttons and adding them to their container looks good.

The only thing I would add is just make sure you are creating the controls on postback too, prior to viewstate being restored, so that the events can actually be called.

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "btn" + i.ToString();
        btn.Tag = i;
        btn.Click += delegate
        {
            if ((int)btn.Tag == 1)
                this.Text = "stack";
        };
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```