# how to execute click event on dynamically created button in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am trying to build an app, where user can select category and according to it displays its sub categories , these sub categories are buttons, which are dynamically created.

Now, as buttons are dynamically created so I am confuse how to write code under button_click event as I dont know how many subcategories are there.

So is there any way I can execute click event of a particular button , so that I can execute certain commands?

**EDITED**

This is the code that i tried

```
Button btnDynamicButton = new Button();

private void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
label2.Text = btnDynamicButton.Text;
}
private void btnappetizer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 groupBox2.Visible =false;
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = itemmasterbl.SelectallrecordFromtblItem(btnappetizer.Text);
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
  string name = "Appetizer" + DynamicButtonCount;
  Button btnDynamicButton1 = new Button();
  btnDynamicButton1.Name = name;
  btnDynamicButton1.Text = name;
  btnDynamicButton1.Size =
  new System.Drawing.Size(150, 30);
  btnDynamicButton1.Location =
  new System.Drawing.Point(180, DynamicButtonCount * 30);
  btnDynamicButton1.Click +=new EventHandler(btnclick_Click);<br>
  Controls.Add(btnDynamicButton1);
  DynamicButtonCount++;
  btnDynamicButton = btnDynamicButton1;
  }
 }
```

Once I do this it creates three buttons according to number of values in itemmaster DB under appetizer, but once I click on any of the three buttons the label displays only last buttons text,because in last line I have :

> btnDynamicButton = btnDynamicButton1;

Which will last buttons infos,but rather I want which ever button I press, label should display respective text. How can I achieve this.

Comment: What UI framework is this? for example, in winforms there is `PerformClick()`. I also wonder if you mean "how do I subscribe to the `Click` event?", rather than "execute click event" - in which case you just *subscribe something to the `Click` event after creating the control* - `newControl.Click += ...`. However, for complex scenarios you may need to use some reflection

Comment: thats the problem I dont know how buttons will be there , so how can i write click event?

Comment: As an alternative, are you sure this is the best way to model this? It almost sounds like a linked set of two listboxes (select a category in the first list, subcategories shown in the second) or a tree view. For large sets of subcategories, you'll be generating a large number of buttons which can be an untidy interface, as well as meaning you can't perform the same action on multiple subcategories at once.

Comment: @Kashif frankly, I suspect you'd do well to have a single fixed handler, and do the voodoo in that single method...

Comment: I am sorry to mention its a touch screen app, so its like a restaurant app where user selects appetizer, main course, desserts etc, and its food menu displays next to it and user selects by clicking on appropriate menu.

Comment: @Kashif It looks like you will have to have to attach the event subscription to the buttons as they are generated. Can you post the code where the buttons are generated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903933/add-event-at-runtime

Comment: @Anandkumar I have checked that, can you please see my edits, I have posted codes as well, will that work here too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can put all your logic into one handler:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Button b = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
//finally insert the button where it needs to be inserted.
...

void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((System.Windows.Forms.Button)sender).Name + " clicked");
}
```

To your edit:

You are storing the reference for your button(s) inside the Field `btnDynamicButton`. Hence it always gets overwritten with the latest button you have created. You should *not* reference the button by using a field. The `sender` parameter of the click-handler contains the button element that has been clicked. See the code above: Simple cast `sender` to `Button` and you know which button has been clicked:

```
private void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)sender
   label2.Text = btn.Text;
}
```

Comment: I think it will work, just tested it, with an example, will post once it executes will actual app.
Thanks