# How do I add buttons with event handlers to a form dynamically?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to do this dynamically? How?

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim c(40) As Integer
Dim IMG As PictureBox
Dim lbl_n(40) As Label
Dim lbl_pr(40) As Label
Dim lbl_ref(40) As Label
Dim lbl_dim(40) As Label
Dim lbl_col(40) As Label
Dim btn_add(40) As Button
Dim btn_rmv(40) As Button
Dim tb_qt(40) As TextBox


AddHandler btn_add(0).Click, AddressOf btn_add0_Click
AddHandler btn_add(1).Click, AddressOf btn_add1_Click
[...]
AddHandler btn_add(40).Click, AddressOf btn_add40_Click

Public Sub btn_add0_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        c(0) = c(0) + 1
        tb_qt(0).Text = c(0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub btn_add1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        c(1) = c(1) + 1
        tb_qt(1).Text = c(1)
    End Sub

    [...]

    Public Sub btn_add40_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        c(40) = c(40) + 1
        tb_qt(40).Text = c(40)
    End Sub
```

These are the images with program running (they are edited):

[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDzWh.png)

[Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cMcA.png)

I want to dynamically, because I could use more than 40 products! And I need to do 40 addhandlers, so that more 40 to remove!
How can I do that?

Comment: Why dont you describe in words that *"this"* is instead of making us read thru your wall of code to figure out what the question is

Comment: You don't need to read the "wall" only if necessary, people maybe coulnd't understand what I'm talking about

Comment: Answer to your question: Yes you can make This dynamically.

Comment: But how can I do that?

Comment: start with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608311/how-to-add-buttons-dynamically-to-my-form then this this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705126/how-to-execute-click-event-on-dynamically-created-button-in-c-net try it, if you have problems post new question on here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can do that dynamically.

In this example, I put those `buttons` and `textboxes` into `Panel`.

There is example with comments which line is for what :

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'dynamically adding buttons (so You don't need create every button separately)
        For x = 1 To 40
            Dim btn As New Button  'create new button
            btn.Name = "btn_add" & x.ToString  'set ID for button (example: btn_add1, btn_add2, ... btn_add40)
            btn.Text = "+"  'set button text
            btn.Tag = x.ToString 'set button NO. for finding corrent textbox whos belong to this button (for example: tb_qt1 belong to buttons btn_add1 and btn_rem1)
            btn.Width = 24 'this is for styling
            btn.Top = (x * btn.Height) + 3 'for styling, too. Top poistion of button
            btn.Left = 0 'for styling, too. Left position of button
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnAdd_Click 'creating sub called btnAdd_Click (this sub will handle all, in this case 40, buttons)
            Panel1.Controls.Add(btn) 'for this example I put buttons and textboxes into panel (autoscroll set to True)
            btn = New Button 'same thing just for remove button
            btn.Name = "btn_rem" & x.ToString
            btn.Text = "-"
            btn.Tag = x.ToString
            btn.Width = 24
            btn.Top = (x * btn.Height) + 3
            btn.Left = btn.Width + 3
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnRem_Click 'creating sub called btnRem_Click (this sub will handle all, in this case 40, buttons)
            Panel1.Controls.Add(btn)
            Dim txt As New TextBox 'same thing for textboxes
            txt.Name = "tb_qt" & x.ToString
            txt.Text = "0"
            txt.Tag = x.ToString
            txt.Top = (x * btn.Height) + 3
            txt.Left = btn.Left + btn.Width + 3
            txt.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
            Panel1.Controls.Add(txt)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)  'detect which button clicked. You can add line: MsgBox(btn.Name) to see what happening
        Dim txt As TextBox = Panel1.Controls.Find("tb_qt" & btn.Tag.ToString, True)(0) 'find textbox which belong to this button. this is why set .Tag into buttons
        txt.Text = CInt(txt.Text) + 1 'just do math and change value, by adding one(1), in textbox (by this way I avoid using Your Dim c(40) As Integer)
    End Sub
    Public Sub btnRem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button) 'same thing like for btnAdd_Click, but we doing subtract for one(1) value in textbox
        Dim txt As TextBox = Panel1.Controls.Find("tb_qt" & btn.Tag.ToString, True)(0)
        txt.Text = CInt(txt.Text) - 1
    End Sub
```

Because I use `panel` like `container` for all those `buttons` and `textboxes`, You have to set `AutoScroll=True` for `panel`.

I hope so You will understand how it's work for start.

Comment: I'm so thankfull! But using `tb_qt.Text`.But It only use the text of the last created control!

Comment: @Silvestre I don't understand what You say... Did You say, posted code affect only last created textbox or...?

Comment: No, it worked fine. But I want to use the Textboxes values' to show in a `ListBox`, but It only works with the last created `TextBox` if I use `tb_qt.Text` !

Comment: @Silvestre ok... how to show in `ListBox`? if some `textbox` value is greater than 0 (zero) have to be show in `ListBox` or You'll have, for example, 40 items in `ListBox` and You need to be updated that items? or... You have to be more specific ... (btw. `ListBox` or `ListView`?)

Comment: It's `ListBox`... doing this: `If tb_qt.Text > 0 Then
            Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add(lbl_ref.Text)
            Form2.ListBox2.Items.Add(lbl_col.Text)
            Form2.ListBox3.Items.Add(lbl_n.Text)
            Form2.ListBox4.Items.Add(lbl_pr.Text)
            Form2.ListBox5.Items.Add(tb_qt.Text)
            Form2.ListBox6.Items.Add(tb_qt.Text * lbl_pr.Text)
        End If` 
It only works with the last created `textbox`

Comment: @Silvestre You have to loop trough all textboxes... for example `For x=1 to 40 Dim txt As TextBox = Panel1.Controls.Find("tb_qt" & x.ToString)(0) If CDec(txt.Text)>0 Then ... *get all labels and so on*... Form2.ListBox5.Items.Add(txt.Text) End If` ... I would recommend You `ListView` (there You can use multicolumns) rather then using so much `ListBoxes` ... there is some interested example : http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/listview-control-with-multiple-column-in-vb.net

Comment: Thanks! It worked now, I created names to all, then I needed to do this: `Dim txt As TextBox = Panel1.Controls.Find("tb_qt" & x.ToString, True)(0)` to all doing their corrections!